# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel conditional formatting based on other cell value

Tags: perl, excel

I'm trying to add conditional formatting in my excel sheet.
Unfortunately examples on Spreadsheet::WriteExcel page are too simple and I don't know how to do it.

I wanted to change row backgroud color by RC10 cell value.
In excel I will add formatting formula

```
=IF(RC10="xxxx";1;0)
```

I've tried to do something like that in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel:

```
my $detail_rest_fmt = $excel->add_format(font => "Calibri", size => 11, valign  => "vcenter", align => "right", border => 1);
$detail_rest_fmt->set_num_format("[Green]=IF(RC10=\"xxxx\";1;0);[Red]=IF(RC10=\"yyyyyy\";1;0)");
```

but withouts any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad news is I think it can hardly be done with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

The good news is it can easily be done with Excel::Writer::XLSX. Which happens to be a kind of descendant of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. Please read the article:
[Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is dead. Long live Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://web.archive.org/web/20140804070349/http://perlbuzz.com/2011/10/spreadsheetwriteexcel-is-dead-long-live-excelwriterxlsx.html)

The following code does exactly the formatting you want (only based on cell A1 instead of RC10, this can be changed of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my @matrix = (
    ['xxxx', '<-- Change the value in cell A1 to change the colour of row 4'],
    [qw(Redyard Kipling)],
    [qw(If--)],
    [qw(If you can keep your head when all about you)],
    [qw(Are losing theirs and blaming it on you;)],
);

writeSpreadsheet('conditional.formatting.xlsx', \@matrix);

sub writeSpreadsheet {
    my ($outFile, $matrix) = @_;
    my $MIN_COL_WIDTH = 5;
    my $MAX_COL_WIDTH = 35;
    my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($outFile);
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
    my $redFormat = $workbook->add_format(font => 'Arial', color => 'red');
    my $greenFormat = $workbook->add_format(font => 'Arial', color => 'green', bold => 1);
    $worksheet->set_row(0, undef,
        $workbook->add_format(font => 'Arial', align => 'center', bold => 1));
    $worksheet->conditional_formatting('A4:Z4',
        {
            type => 'formula',
            criteria => '=$A$1 = "xxxx"',
            format => $greenFormat
        }
    );
    $worksheet->conditional_formatting('A4:Z4',
        {
            type => 'formula',
            criteria => '=$A$1 = "yyyyyy"',
            format => $redFormat
        }
    );
    foreach my $row (0 .. $#$matrix) {
        foreach my $col (0 .. $#{$matrix->[$row]}) {
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $matrix->[$row][$col] || '');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anton, is correct. Conditional formatting isn't really supported in [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/).

However, the newer, API compatible replacement, [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) offers a rich set of conditional formatting features.

See the updated [Conditional Formatting](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING_IN_EXCEL) docs in Excel::Writer::XLSX and this [example](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example%3a_conditional_format.pl).

Comment: API of WriteExcel is full compatible with XLSX?

Comment: Yes. See the [Excel::Writer::XLSX and Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#Excel::Writer::XLSX_and_Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Behavior of conditional_formatting is very strange.
I got something like that:

```
my $yyy = $excel->add_format(font => "Calibri", size => 11, valign  => "vcenter", align => "right", border => 1, border_color => "black", bg_color => $green);

for my $section (@sections) {
   for my $sector (@sectors) {
       my $xxxx = $excel->add_format(font => "Calibri", size => 11, valign  => "vcenter", align => "right", border => 1, border_color => "black", bg_color => $green);
            $sheet->conditional_formatting("A1", 
            {
                type => "formula",
                criteria => '=J4="T1"',
                format => $yyy
            });
   }
}
```

When I use $yyy it dosen't work (in excel there is set pattern fill instead of backgroud color)
When I use $xxxx it works fine.
$yyy and $xxxx are the same, so why it doesn't work?

Comment: It seems to that I cannot use $format before, it has to be "fresh" new one... it makes non sense.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:

You may be encountering an issue where the formats are getting garbage collected before you get to use them due to scope issues.

If it is a scope problem try add a `$workbook->close()` to the end of your program to see if it fixes it.

Otherwise we would need a more complete example program to debug it.